# Web page at data:text/html not available with certain WebView text/html content strings

Tags: android, character-encoding, android-webview

I am using the following Java code to create some HTML for displaying content.

```
public String htmlFromArrayList(ArrayList<TSI> a) {

    StringBuilder returnStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (TSI i : a) {
        returnStringBuilder.append("<h3>");
        returnStringBuilder.append(i.itemTitle);
        returnStringBuilder.append("</h3><p>");
        returnStringBuilder.append(i.itemText);
        returnStringBuilder.append("</p>");
    }

    return returnStringBuilder.toString();
}
```

To load the string I use

```
mWebView.loadData(htmlFromArrayList(mSummaryItemArrayList), "text/html", null);
```

Now this works for about 60% to 70% of my `ArrayList<TSI>`, but for the others I get an error when I open the `TSI`:

`The web page at data:text/html;null,%3Cp%E.......p%3E might be temporarily down or it may have moved...`

I am assuming this has something to do with strange characters in the charset.  What does the error message mean?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20356555/236743

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have strange characters like percent signs, backslashes or other non alphabetical characters in your i.itemText or i.itemTitle?  If you do, that will cause the 'webpage not found' problem.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4401

Also, you are not passing in an Encoding, try passing in "UTF-8" instead of null.

```
mWebView.loadData(htmlFromArrayList(mSummaryItemArrayList), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

This problem can be worked around by replacing all % symbols with the HTML entity (Ampersand Pound 37): (&#37).

There are reports that if any Chinese characters get fed into your webView, you can still get the "page not found" problem even if you handle the percent sign.  So the work around is to try this:

**This works with everything plus Chinese characters:**

```
mWebView.loadData(URLEncoder.encode(html,"utf-8").replaceAll("\\+"," "), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

**Source**
http://code.google.com/p/android-rss/issues/detail?id=15

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes... I do. Can I either specify a particular charset for browser to use or convert my charset into one that is more browser friendly?

Comment: Thanks so much for this common, non-obvious solution! I use it as a utility method now--makes using WebViews much easier. public static void loadAndCleanData(WebView webView, String html) {
  try {
   webView.loadData(
     URLEncoder.encode(html, "utf-8").replaceAll("\\+", " "),
     "text/html", "utf-8");
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
   throw new RuntimeException(
     "utf-8 encoding failed when loading String into WebView");
  }
 }

Comment: Thanks, this one solved my problem. Most of the html strings I load to my webview are working fine but there are some that experienced this kind of problem. Just needed to encode the string UTF-8 and everything works as expected