# Android 2.3 webview loadData just shows encoded characters

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to use a webview with loadData to display an image:

```
        String data = "<html><head><title>Photo</title></head>";
        data = data + "<body><center><img width=\"100%\" src=\"" + imageUrl + "\" /></center></body></html>";

        imageWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        imageWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        imageWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        imageWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        imageWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        imageWebView.loadData(data, "text/html", "UTF-8");
        imageWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

In the 4.1 emulator this works ok and I can see the image.  In 2.3 it just displays encoded html code.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing this?  I have some HTML that isn't being rendered in a webview on pre 4.0

Comment: Unfortunately I have not found out why this happens.

Comment: If you're imageUrl paramater has naughty characters (naughty for urls ?, %, etc) then you should url encode all your data going into loadData like this: URLEncoder.encode(data).replaceAll("\\+"," ")

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be caused by a [known bug in WebView](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4401), where if you have any percentages in the supplied data, the data is interpret as a URL.

A known workaround is, as mentioned in the bug report, to replace all `%` with `&#37;`.

Another workaround that seems to work quite well is suggested in a [similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317977/web-page-at-datatext-html-not-available-with-certain-webview-text-html-cont) and should also cover any other characters that may cause the same issue:

```
mWebView.loadData(URLEncoder.encode(data,"utf-8").replaceAll("\\+"," "), "text/html", "utf-8");
```