# Android WebView with load Data not give proper output in chinese text

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview

I have load html page in Android Web View
In this html page text is Chinese so it's not properly display in web view
text read from database and show in Web view

**My code is**

```
wvContentDesc = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Wv_content_desc);
wvContentDesc.loadData(articlesBean.content, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: Might be a device specific problem...are you using emulator or device? Just check if that content shows in default browser (not programmatically: take your content in a separate html file and open it manually)

Comment: You have to use `loadDataWithBaseURL` instead `loadData`. and put css and js file in assets folder if any. Refer this [how-to-create-update-load-a-html-file-at-runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416182/how-to-create-update-load-a-html-file-at-runtime/18417164#18417164)

Comment: @user2450263 i am working in Device In Device Browser Display properly but in Web View not Display properly

Comment: @BlackTiger  my data come from Data base so not possible to set file in assets folder

Comment: @DhavalShah: i m not tell about your html data.. i specified that if any css or js you use then need to store in assets..

Comment: @DhavalShah : check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317977/web-page-at-datatext-html-not-available-with-certain-webview-text-html-content